# NameError: name 'entry1' is not defined during file path print in entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I am struggling with the output of an filepath into an Entry Widget.
I want to select a CSV file with a Button and then put the file path into an Entry Widget. The initial text of this Entry Widget should be replaced in this case.

Unfortunately I got the following message:
NameError: name 'entry1' is not defined

Could you please give me some hints, why this operation failed?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "This is my GUI")
        tk.Tk.minsize(self, 640, 480)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="True")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in [StartPage]:
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label1 = ttk.Label(self, text="Look at my GUI")
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="File 1:")
        label2.grid(row=1, column=0)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Browse File", command=browse_directory1)
        button1.grid(row=1, column=2)

        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, width=50)
        entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        entry1.insert(END, '"Open File 1"')
        entry1.config(state=DISABLED)


def browse_directory1():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="../", title="Select a File", filetype=(("CSV File", "*.csv"), ("Excel File", "*.xls"), ("All files", "*.*")))

    print(filename)

    entry1.configure(state=NORMAL)
    entry1.delete(0, "end")
    entry1.insert(0, filename)
    entry1.config(state=DISABLED)


app = GUI()
app.mainloop()
´´´´
```

Comment: ***" NameError: name 'entry1' is not defined"***: That's correct, `entry1` is `local` to `def __init__(...` and furthermore `def browse_directory1()` is not a member of `class StartPage `. Read about [scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by giving the `entry1` variable to `browsedirectory` with a lambda.
For do this I reversed entry build with button1.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "This is my GUI")
        tk.Tk.minsize(self, 640, 480)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="True")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in [StartPage]:
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label1 = ttk.Label(self, text="Look at my GUI")
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="File 1:")
        label2.grid(row=1, column=0)

        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, width=50)
        entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        entry1.insert(END, '"Open File 1"')
        entry1.config(state=DISABLED)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Browse File",
                             command = lambda e = entry1: browse_directory1(e))
        button1.grid(row=1, column=2)


def browse_directory1(entry1):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="../", title="Select a File", filetype=(("CSV File", "*.csv"), ("Excel File", "*.xls"), ("All files", "*.*")))

    print(filename)

    entry1.configure(state=NORMAL)
    entry1.delete(0, "end")
    entry1.insert(0, filename)
    entry1.config(state=DISABLED)


app = GUI()
app.mainloop()
```